# Is it possible to add multiple variables in the same regression model?

Tags: r, regression, lm, summary

These are the regression models that I want to obtain. I want to select many variables at the same time to develop a multivariate model, since my data frame has 357 variables.

summary(lm(formula = bci_bci ~ bti_acp, data = qog))

summary(lm(formula = bci_bci ~ wdi_pop, data = qog))

summary(lm(formula = bci_bci ~ ffp_sl, data = qog))

Comment: `summary(lm(bci_bci ~ bti_acp + new_variable_1 + new_variable_2 + ....+ new_variable_n, data = qog))`

Comment: Also bci_bci ~ . where the right hand side is just a dot will use all columns in the data as predictors other than the column used for the dependent variable.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of listing all your variables using `+` signs, you can also use the shorthand notation `.` to add all variables in `data` as explanatory variables (except the target variable on the left hand side of course).

```r
data("mtcars")
mod <- lm(mpg ~ ., data = mtcars)
summary(mod)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = mpg ~ ., data = mtcars)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
#> -3.4506 -1.6044 -0.1196  1.2193  4.6271 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
#> (Intercept) 12.30337   18.71788   0.657   0.5181  
#> cyl         -0.11144    1.04502  -0.107   0.9161  
#> disp         0.01334    0.01786   0.747   0.4635  
#> hp          -0.02148    0.02177  -0.987   0.3350  
#> drat         0.78711    1.63537   0.481   0.6353  
#> wt          -3.71530    1.89441  -1.961   0.0633 .
#> qsec         0.82104    0.73084   1.123   0.2739  
#> vs           0.31776    2.10451   0.151   0.8814  
#> am           2.52023    2.05665   1.225   0.2340  
#> gear         0.65541    1.49326   0.439   0.6652  
#> carb        -0.19942    0.82875  -0.241   0.8122  
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 2.65 on 21 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.869,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.8066 
#> F-statistic: 13.93 on 10 and 21 DF,  p-value: 3.793e-07

par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(mod)
```

[image]

```r
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

If you want to include all two-way interactions, the notation would be this:

```r
lm(mpg ~ (.)^2, data = mtcars)
```

If you want to include all three-way interactions, the notation would be this:

```r
lm(mpg ~ (.)^3, data = mtcars)
```

If you create very large models (with many variables or interactions), make sure that you also perform some model size reduction after that, e.g. using the function `step()`. It's very likely that not all your predictors are actually going to be informative, and many could be correlated, which causes problems in multivariate models. One way out of this could be to remove any predictors that are highly correlated to other predictors from the model.